# Social login not working when password policy is implemented

Tags: social-connected, membership-provider

In our website(Sitecore 8.2 u5), we have a user registration page and also the social login option.

For the social login, we are using the in-built Social connector module.
When user logs in using their social network account for the first time, Sitecore will create a new user with any password. This is working fine.

However, for a change request, we had to implement a password policy with some standard specifications like one uppercase, one symbol etc.

This was implemented as a web.config setting where you can give a regular expression in the `membership` node.

For the custom registration form, the user entered password is matched & validated with the regular exprn. and this is working fine.

Issue is now with the social login. The account is not created when a new user logs via social network and there is a Facebook error that says "password not valid".

I guess it is happening because, when Sitecore is generating a new password, it isn't matching with the regular exprn./password policy. Is that correct?

1. Does Sitecore create same password for every social login.
2. Is there a way that I can tell Sitecore to bypass this policy, if it is a social login.
3. If option 2 is not possible, can we make Sitecore to create social login accounts with one custom password, either by any config setting or code.